# python subprocess call from wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, mod-wsgi

When I run the exact same function from the python3 interpreter vs, apache via mod wsgi, they both run error free but one returns the command text from apache the stout is simply always blank. Again I am running the exact same function.

Backgorund, I want to run svn update on some code to do so I am using subprocess to  simply call "svn update /path/to/repo"

```
def update():
    p1=subprocess.Popen(["svn", "update", "/var/www/myrepocode"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (ret, stderr) = p1.communicate(timeout=10)
    return (str(ret.decode('utf-8')))
```

when i run from the python3 shell or another python 3 script called from the shell

```
from test import update
print(update())
```

it works fine and i get
"Updating '/var/www/myrepocode':\nAt revision 27.\n"

when I have a wsgi script and execute it from accessing the web page

```
def application(environ, start_response):
...
     output = output + "---"+update() +"---"
...
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', 
str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output.encode('utf-8')]
```

I get an empty string:

```
------
```

I do not have a python virtual environment, just normal python3 and there are no errors thrown either. I suspect this has to do with the user running it but I really don't know. setting shell=True doesn't change anything either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your update method does not return nor print `stderr` .  Maybe you should check for errors first by adding the following line in the update method.

```
print(stderr)
```

If errors are produced, can you post them?